# Libjpeg-9d: ./configure --disable-shared still produce .so files on Linux

Tags: linux, makefile, configure, alpine-linux, libjpeg

I am trying to build jpeg-9d library from sources on Alpine Linux (3.14.2).
I would like to obtain only static libraries (`.a` files) from libjpeg.
This is because I would like to get all 3rd party dependencies all-in-one into my application. And this is because I chose Alpine Linux due static musl C library.

The compilation actually was fine, all configure step, make, make install went fine.

```
./configure --disable-shared
make
make install
```

But after this I see libjpeg.so file in `/usr/local/lib` directory.
Actually both libjpeg.a and libjpeg.so are present in `/usr/local/lib`.

install.txt says that using `--disable-shared` should be enough.
But it does not work.

I built many 3rd party libraries into static configuration on Alpine Linux;
all of them produced `.a` files only (of course, I used additional configuration flags),
like zlib, bzip2, xz, zstd, libpng, giflib (small patch was required), expat, freetype2, fontconfig, json, openssl, tiff, boost, etc.

Previously I used libjpeg-6b, and instead of using just make install I used

```
make install-lib
```

command and I got only `.a` files. Old jpeg-6b supported `install-lib` target. But the new libjpeg-9d does not support this target in make files.

I think it is a bug in jpeg-9d configuration scripts.
Any chance to work-around it or even fix?

Comment: File a bug to libjpeg.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know contacts of IJG libjpeg support. Neither https://www.ijg.org/ or https://jpegclub.org/ have support contacts.

Comment: Open the readme file in your distribution?

Comment: Ok, thank you, really it has some contact email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `--enable-shared=no` works fine, no `.so` files are copied into `/usr/local/lib`!

So, I can use `--enable-shared=no` instead of `--disable-shared`.

```
./configure --enable-shared=no
make
make install
```

Maybe it is an issue of automake/autoconf Alpine Linux utilities.